# Dynamically create variables in template files based on list

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a task definition json file which is created via a templatefile.

Something like the below:

```
data "template_file" "task_definition" {
  templatefile = file("${path.module}/templates/task-definition.json")

  vars {
    environment = var.environment
  }
```

Within the json file (aka the task definition), I have some variables which could be a list. However the app expects them to be split. Something like the below:

```
      {
        "name": "MyEnvironmentVariable:0",
        "value": "123"
      },
      {
        "name": "MyEnvironmentVariable:1",
        "value": "456"
      },
```

In Production, there could be 10 of these (i.e. go all the way up to `MyEnvironmentVariable:10`), but in some testing environments it could be 2 or even 0.

How can I handle that use-case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking a slightly different approach which I think is more readable in the long-run, especially to people who may not have worked with Terraform before.

I basically removed all the environment variables from the template (instead of a half/half situation I was getting into originally):

```
"environment": ${task_def_environment_vars},
```

I passed a local of *all* the environment variables I needed:

```
task_def_environment_vars = jsonencode(local.task_def_environment_vars),
```

And created that list by combining two lists:

```
task_def_environment_vars = concat(local.common_task_def_environment_vars, var.specific_task_def_environment_vars)
```

One list is common across all environments so no need for duplication. This can be predictable variables or hard-coded values that I want to be consistent across environments/workspaces.

The other list is a specific set of variables depending on which environment/workspace. These are for variables which may exist for dev/qa builds but are not present in production and vice-versa. This list is stored in `variables/` folder which contains different files for different environments/workspaces and is selected at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

There are some details missing from your question so I'm making some assumptions.

First, it sounds like your "environment" input variable is a map of lists of strings:

```
variable "environment" {
  type = map(list(string))
}
```

The JSON file you need to generate here needs to to flatten this into a single-level list while appending the indices to avoid conflicts between multiple values of the same name.

The following expression should get the data structure you need:

```
locals {
  environment_flat = tolist(flatten([
    for name, values in var.environment : [
      for i, value in values : {
        name  = length(values) > 1 ? "${name}:${i}" : name
        value = value
      }
    ]
  ]))
}
```

You can access this data structure elsewhere in you module using `local.environment_flat`.

---

The `template_file` data source from the `hashicorp/template` provider has been obsolete since 2019 so you should not use it as part of any modern Terraform module.

If you want to generate JSON then I would suggest using [the `jsonencode` function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/jsonencode).

If your JSON data structure is complicated enough for it to be helpful to write the expression that generates it in a separate file then you can use [the `templatefile` function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/templatefile) as modern a replacement for the `template_file` data source. If you choose this option, please refer to [Generating JSON or YAML from a Template](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/templatefile#generating-json-or-yaml-from-a-template) to see how to write a `jsonencode` call inside your external template file, so that you can avoid generating JSON by string concatenation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I ended up solving it in a different way in the end. 

However I did switch out the deprecated method and instead used the templatefile function so I appreciate you pointing that out to me.